# "Filter failed" stopping all printing - Xerox

Tags: printing, xerox

On Monday morning, my local printer (Xerox Phaser 3320) would not accept jobs ("printing stopped"). I have access to network printers (all Xerox), and had the same experience with them. I have now spent the better part of yesterday and today trying to solve this problem: everything was working fine until I got the weekend's updates. (At least, I was printing just fine on Friday.)

I have scoured this site, Unix.SE, and the internet for "filter failed" problems, but can't find a solution that works in my case. I've tried deleting and re-installing the printer several times, from Settings, and `sudo system-config-printer`, and `http://localhost:631/`, and also checked cables, etc., all to no avail.

I have tried using the PPD suggested by the system, as well as the one [available from the Xerox site](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-3320/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en).

I have Win7 in a Virtualbox on this machine, and *can* (!) print to this printer from Virtuabox.

With the latest re-install, I tried printing a test-page (from the install device settings window), and get this in `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] ================================================
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] File: <STDIN>
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] ================================================
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] Xerox-Phaser-3320: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqpdf.so.18: version `LIBQPDF_18\' not found (required by Xerox-Phaser-3320)
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] Cannot process \"<STDIN>\": Unknown filetype.
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] Process is dying with \"Could not print file <STDIN>
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] \", exit stat 2
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] Cleaning up...
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] PID 21028 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) stopped with status 1.
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] PID 21030 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/dnssd) exited with no errors.
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] PID 21029 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/foomatic-rip) stopped with status 2.
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] PDF template file doesn\'t have form. It\'s okay.
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] PID 21027 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf) did not catch or ignore signal 13.
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] End of messages
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] printer-state=3(idle)
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] printer-state-message="Filter failed"
D [19/Sep/2017:13:12:53 +0100] [Job 70] printer-state-reasons=none
```

I note the problem with `libqpdf.so.18`, and this is what the location shows:

```
$ ls -al libqpdf*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Aug 18 15:06 libqpdf.so.17 -> libqpdf.so.17.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 751928 Aug 18 15:06 libqpdf.so.17.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Sep 16 04:12 libqpdf.so.18 -> libqpdf.so.18.1.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 784600 Sep 16 04:12 libqpdf.so.18.1.0
```

Beyond that, however, I don't know what this problem might represent or how to fix it.

I am running (full disclosure) Ubuntu Gnome 17.10 but hope I don't have to wait weeks for some help with this problem. (Please!) I would welcome any suggestions or guidance on further diagnostic steps.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with a different Printer.

Looks like it is related to this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-filters/+bug/1718215. So hopefully it will be solved with the next version of the package `cups-filters-core-drivers 1.17.7`.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st line tells you `Xerox-Phaser-3320: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqpdf.so.18: version 
 'LIBQPDF_18\' not found (required by Xerox-Phaser-3320)` that you need version 18 of the `libqpdf` library.

The `libqpdf18` package is available with Artful, but not backported yet, AFAIK.

One could install `apt-src`, then use `apt-src` to download the Source and Dependencies, compile it yourself, ....

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed the `libgutenprintui2-2` and `libcupsimage2` packages.

If not, try to install them.

Package names may vary across different *nix distros (and to an extent across releases of the same distro), but you can search for similar one .